# I have a custom TabLayout with 4 items which only has texts.I want each texts in my tabLayout to be equidistant

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

My TabLayout requires this

1. Equidistant text
   [image: like this]
2. Left and right padding are constant.
3. All texts should be the same size
4. Tabs should not be scrollable
   *** the texts on each tab can have any length of characters

Answer (score 1):

Create a new style in `styles.xml`

```
<!-- TabTextSizeAppearance to define your tab text size -->
<style name="TabTextSizeAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<!-- MyTabLayout to define TabLayout parameters -->
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTextSizeAppearance</item>
</style>
```

And finally, add this to your `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="design_tab_text_size_2line" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">14sp</dimen>
```

This `dimen` size should be the same as `TabTextSizeAppearance` text size to ensure text is the same size even if with long text

Then use it in your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyTabLayout"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      ...


</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```